# exporting js prototype class using an IIFE

Tags: javascript

I seem to be having an issue while exporting a prototype class.

To give an example:

```js
/* eslint no-shadow:0 */
var UtilityManager = (function(w, d, c) {
 function UtilityManager() {
  c.log('UtilityManager created!');
 }

 UtilityManager.prototype.extendObject = function(base, extending) {
  var key;

  if (typeof extending !== 'object') {
   c.warn('Extending object is not of type Object');
   extending = {};
  }

  for (key in extending) {
   if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(base, key)) {
    base[key] = extending[key];
   }
  }

  return base;
 };

 return UtilityManager;
}(window, document, console));

export default UtilityManager;
```

When I try and access this code using

```
UtilityManager = require('./helpers/dfp.utility');
UtilityManager = new UtilityManager();
```

First I hoped this would work:

```
UtilityManager = new (require('./helpers/dfp.utility'))();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't. Explanation welcome :)
Anyways, when running the code I get following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: UtilityManager is not a constructor

How come?

Comment: That is not a CommonJS export. try `import UtilityManager  from "./helpers/dfp.utility"`

Comment: Or conversely, `modules.export = UtilityManager`. Nor is it at all clear why you need an IIFE when you're not closing over any free variables.

Comment: Also, whatever module system you are using, all of them have module scopes so you don't need any IIFE at all.